# How to find out if a SharePoint 2010 workflow ran in last 4 months?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a SharePoint 2010 workflow, which is associated with a document library. I want to know if the workflow ran in last 4 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workflow history list will contain information on when your workflow last ran, you can find the list in your site. Here is an example of the list URL:

https://sharepoint/mysite/lists/Workflow%20History/AllItems.aspx

Comment: Just curious, what if user is not logging anything to workflow history list? will it still contain information on when your workflow last ran? Also, what if user has created new workflow history list for this particular workflow (I guess user cannot be access it using the link you provided)?

Comment: Yes, I believe SharePoint logs information here regarding the status of the workflow. If the user has chosen to create their own workflow history list then they will be aware of where to find their workflow history already.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the document library -> Click workflow settings in the library tab -> Check whether SharePoint 2010 workflow ran in last 4 months.